# Pencil of irreducible cubics must have $9$ distinct base points?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, surfaces, elliptic-curves

Let $\mathcal{L}$ be a pencil of cubics on $\Bbb{P}_\Bbb{C}^2$ whose general member is smooth and such that all members are irreducible.

I'm trying to prove/disprove the following:

> The base locus of $\mathcal{L}$ consists of nine $9$ distinct points.

I do have an intuitive argument, but formally speaking I'm still lost.

The argument is: let $C,C'$ be smooth cubics. Generally, $C,C'$ meet in $9$ distinct points $P_1,...,P_9$ in the most general position possible (i.e., no three points are in a line, no six are in a conic). Let $\mathcal{L}'$ is the pencil of cubics through $P_1,...,P_9$. The fact that $\mathcal{L}$ has only irreducible curves should mean that it is general in some sense, therefore essentially like $\mathcal{L}'$.

I've tried to formalize this by looking at $\Bbb{P}^9$ as the space of all cubics in $\Bbb{P}^2$ and $\mathcal{L}$ as a general line in it. But I don't know how to relate this with the condition of $9$ distinct points.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Think along these lines: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Bacharach_theorem#Details

Comment: @Servaes Suppose we are given points $P_1,...,P_8$ in general position. The linear system of cubics through $P_1,....,P_8$ has dimension 1. If $C$ is a cubic in it, then any choice of $P_9\in C$ determines a unique pencil of cubics, namely the ones through $P_1,...,P_9$. Correct?

Comment: Now suppose we choose $P_9$ infinitely near $P_8$ (in other words, we let $P_8$ have multiplicity two). This will also determine a linear system of cubics, say $\mathcal{P}$. If the conjecture in this post is true, $\mathcal{P}$ must have a reducible element. Is this true? To be honest, I don't know